# AppEngine Scheduled Task syntax for a task to run after X years

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a task that needs to run every 4 years in my application. How can I configure that in cron.xml. I know that `<schedule>1 of Jan</schedule>` would run it yearly but is there a syntax for running it after X years something like `<schedule>every 4 years 1 of Jan</schedule>` ?

-Srikanth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documented [schedule format](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron#Java_appengine_web_xml_The_schedule_format) doesn't seem to have support for what you desire.

You could convert such very long intervals in hours and use this format instead (might be tricky to get exact dates/times in some cases - leap years, etc):

> every N hours

I just tried a number of hours equivalent to over 4 years, the development server doesn't seem unhappy:

[image]

Another possible approach (which also allows precise date/time specs) is to invoke the task yearly as you mentioned, keep track inside your app of the last execution date or the number of invocations and only execute the actual task's job in 1 out of 4 invocations and simply exiting without doing anything in the other 3 invocations.